# Understanding how a loop of recursive calls work

Tags: loops, for-loop, recursion

I'm really new to recusivity, and i stumbled across an exercise in which we have a loop making several recursive calls, and i did not understand, how it is working.

Look at the example below :

```
int calculateSomething (int n) {

 if (n > 100)
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   calculateSomething(n+1);
}
```

Suppose i make a first call to calculateSomething(200), how many calls i'm gonna have ? At first glimpse i would say 100*10, so 1000 calls ?

Does "i" goes along way to 10 for each call ? Or it makes a call for each value of "i" ?

I'm sorry to ask such a question but i'm really blocked XD

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no such thing as *recursivity*, the word is **recursion** :)

Comment: Sorry ! It is a French, English mix lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you had given does not have a return statement even though return type is int. Moreover it will go on infinitely because there is no end condition.

This would be the execution cycle

call 1: n=200 i=0 calculateSomething(201)

call 2: n=201 i=0 calculateSomething(202)

call 3: n=202 i=0 calculateSomething(203) ....

*Does "i" goes along way to 10 for each call ? Or it makes a call for each value of "i" ?*

Makes a call for each value of i. Recursion works with a stack (Last in First out). In simple program say I call Method1 from main and Method2 from Method1, the stack that would look like this

Method2

Method1

main

Basically the last one called will be at the top and once that completes it will go to next one.

Since you are new to this start with a simpler example like factorial

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println(n + " "+ (n-1));
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

If you call factorial(3) then stack would look like

1 (since factorial(1-1) i.e factorial(0) is 0)

1 * factorial(1-1)

2 * factorial(2-1)

3 * factorial(3-1)

factorial(3) ---> the actual method call

Now every time a call returns here it will replace the factorial(n-1) in the  one below it with the actual value i.e

factorial(1-1) will be replaced by 1

factorial(2-1) will be replaced by 1 * 1

factorial(3-1) will be replaced by 2 * (1 * 1)

factorial(3) becomes 3 * (2 * (1 * 1))

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes ! It helps clearing the concept a bit ! My real problem besides the ones answred, is having to know how much calls i make with example in the first answer ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The example you gave is infinite.Take this `int calculateSomething(int n){if (n<10){for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++){calculateSomething(n + 1);}}return 0;}`.This will not execute just 5*10 times.You need to find a pattern.If you call calculateSomething(0) then initially it will go all the way upto 9 and then starts coming down.When n=9 the loop will execute 5 times. When n=8 loop will execute 5 times and for each of this 5 n=9 will be execute 5 times.This is because of the recursive call n+1.

Comment: Put this in a java code and debug it. That will give you a better idea.

Comment: Thank you very much svikkiram ! It really helps !

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your example code will lend on an infinite loop, `if( n>100 )` will be avaluated as TRUE on all your recursive calls because your "n" value always increase. `calculateSomething(n+1)`

If you call `calculateSomething(200)`, the first recursive call will be inside the for loop with `i=0`, `CalclulateSomething(201)`

Then forget about the next iterations of the for loop until the recursive call ends , and as I explained before, it will never happen.

```
calculateSomething(200)
  -> i=0 calculateSomething(201)
    -> i=0 calculateSomething(202)
      -> i=0 calculateSomething(203)
        -> ...infinite...
```

Take the next code as example:
(Fixed the infinite loop, and reduced the values for explanation)

```
int calculateSomething (int n) {

 if (n < 3)
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   calculateSomething(n+1);
}
```

The recursive calls will be:

```
calculateSomething(0)
  -> i=0 calculateSomething(1)

    -> i=0 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

     -> i=1 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

     -> i=2 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

  -> i=1 calculateSomething(1)

     -> i=0 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

     -> i=1 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

     -> i=2 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

   -> i=2 calculateSomething(1)

     -> i=0 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

     -> i=1 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE

     -> i=2 calculateSomething(2)

       -> i=0 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=1 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
       -> i=2 calculateSomething(3)
         -> end. if (n < 3) = FALSE
```

If you want to calculate the number of times your function is called, you can simply add a conunter and increment it for every call, something like:

```
int counter = 0;  // declaring it on a global scope

int calculateSomething (int n) {

    counter++;

    if (n < 3)
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       calculateSomething(n+1);
    }
```

Comment: Oh ! Exactly what i was looking for ! A big thanks for you ! I really appreciate ! BTW it was just a mistake on the example ! Sorry :(

Comment: And how can we calculte the number of calls of such a method ?

Comment: @IgZiStO Create an incremental variable, pass it to the recursive function (ex. `calculateSomething(number, count++)`), and return its value in the end of the function (`return count;`)